# How to improve performance on a SQL database table that has 60 million rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a table that has 60 million rows in a Postgresql database.

Table is as follows:

```
id varchar PK
cutomerId Integer
orderId Integer
modified timestamp.
```

Now I want to create a summary of customer and number of orders on a particular day for example

```
SELECT customerId, COUNT(orderId) 
FROM orders o  
WHERE DATE(o.modified) = '2023-04-27' GROUP by customerId
```

This takes up to 5 minutes to return in SQL query UI.

Is there any way I can speed this up?

Comment: I'd try `where o.modified >= timestamp'2023-04-27 00:00:00' and o.modified < timestamp'2023-04-28 00:00:00'`.

Comment: BTW, you need a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: That query doesn't run. It needs a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: which indexes do you have in your table?

Comment: Create index on 'modified' column and use between in where o.modified between '2023-04-27 00:00:00' and '2023-04-27 23:59:59'

Comment: Perhaps better asked on the sister site dba.StackExchange.com

Answer (score -1):

For this specific query, you could create an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON orders(DATE(o.modified), customerId, orderId);
```

And as always with any performance issue, you need the query execution plan and you can create it using

> EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) *your_sql_here*;

Without this information, you can only guess what's going on.